# How to make changing a <select>'s default value in ng-model as a change that can activate the function in ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select name="BF_base_type" id="BF_base_type" 
style="display:inline height:20px;" 
ng-model="BF_base_type"  
ng-change="activateDiv('Model_BF','BF_base_type')" 
ng-options="start.value as start.name for start in startOptions"> </select>
```

In above , there is default value ="BF_base_type" for the selection given by ng-model. There is a function for ng-change, which will activate once there is a change happened to the selection.

What I wanted to have is to activate ng-change function by checking the default value for the selection specified by ng-model, no matter there is change or not by user interaction.

For example. By default, BF_base_type is empty or not defined. So  is empty. Upon user's interaction,  BF_base_type will be assigned a non-empty value. By observation, assigning a non-empty value to  BF_base_type would not activate the function associated to ng-change.

How can I activate the function associated to ng-change for changing the value of the variable (BF_base_type in this case) assigned to ng-model from one (empty or null) to another (non-empty, none)?

Thanks...

Comment: As it's ng-model, you must avoid `quotes` in that function for `BF_base_type`. It will take it as string

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ng-init` line to trigger it at the beginning:

```
<select name="BF_base_type" id="BF_base_type" 
style="display:inline height:20px;" 
ng-model="BF_base_type"  
ng-change= "activateDiv('Model_BF', BF_base_type)"
ng-init  = "activateDiv('Model_BF', BF_base_type)"
ng-options="start.value as start.name for start in startOptions"> </select>
```

By the way do you really want the quotes around `BF_base_type` in your `ng-change`? If you do so you'll get the string, without them you'll get the value.